# Upgrade to trusty from saucy without full upgrade

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I've modified most of my Ubuntu 13.10 by removing Unity etc. Now running `do-release-upgrade -d` gives a huge list of upgrades that re-adds some of the packages I removed etc.

I'd like to just upgrade the existing packages to 14.04 packages **without** installing a bulk of new packages that I previously uninstalled. How can I do this?

Comment: Gnome Shell is not provided by Ubuntu 13.10 by any default. Please provide more details.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant unity desktop environment etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did an upgrade manually by changing the distribution to "trusty" from "saucy" in /etc/apt/sources.list and changed the distribution tags of ppa's in the same manner.

Then I manually upgraded the packages through synaptic.